# Twilio messages - I cant access data properties

Tags: laravel, twilio

I have Twilio integrated into my app. I send and texts, receive texts and display them all.

This is my collection of data

```
$receivedMessages = $twilio->messages
                     ->read(array(
                             "from" => $user->phone,
                             "to" => $siteNumber,
                         )
                     );

 $sentMessages = $twilio->messages
                     ->read(array(
                             "from" => $siteNumber,
                             "to" => $user->phone,
                         )
                     );
```

I can't access any of the date related properties from this list in my blade template. https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message#message-properties.

I get the error Unknown property:

I can use all the others eg body, direction.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried  $sentMessages->dateCreated ???

Comment: Yes. That doesn't work. The same error of "unknown property" appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($sentMessages as $message) {
            var_dump($message->date_created);
        }
```